# Shared variables in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp, shared-memory

I have a very basic question (maybe stupid) regarding shared variables in OpenMP. Consider the following code:

```
void main()
{
int numthreads;
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(numthreads)
 {
  numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  printf("%d\n",numthreads);
 }
}
```

Now the value of `numthreads` is the same for all threads. is there a possibility that since various threads are *writing the same value to the same variable*, the value might get garbled/mangled ? Or is this operation on a *primitive datatype* guaranteed to be atomic ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the standard, this is not safe:

> A single access to a variable may be implemented with multiple load or store instructions, and
>   hence is not guaranteed to be atomic with respect to other accesses to the same variable.
>   [...]
>   If multiple threads write without synchronization to the same memory unit, including cases due to
>   atomicity considerations as described above, then a data race occurs. [...] If a data race occurs then **the result of the program is unspecified**.

I strongly recommend reading [1.4.1 Structure of the OpenMP Memory Model](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).  While it's not the easiest read, it's very specific and quite clear. By far better than I could describe it here.

Two things need to be considered about shared variables in OpenMP: *atomicity* of access and the *temporary view of memory*.

Comment: In practice, int should be aligned and would turn out to be atomic.  The race condition could affect performance even though it shouldn't result in errors if the value doesn't change.

Comment: I too would be very surprised to see the program producing a wrong result in practice. Nevertheless it's unspecified, implementation defined and not portable.

Comment: @Zulan: Thank you. In practice I've never gotten a "bad" value for numthreads but today while writing this a doubt arose which has been put to rest. +1 to tim18 for bringing the performance issue up. I will read the memory model as soon as I get time. Thank you again for your efforts.